# Batch script to release project using maven

Tags: maven, batch-file

I wish to write a batch script to automate the project release .The following commands are to be included in the script. However the script should check if the earlier command has completed successfully and then proceed to the next command.

```
1.svn co https://projectbase/svn/projectname/trunk
2.mvn clean install
3.mvn release:prepare
4.mvn release:perform
```

I know that I should use call for the mvn commands but, how do I write the batch script to check the successful completion of one command and then proceed to the next command in the batch script ?

Comment: I would like to encourage you to use the CI, http://jenkins-ci.org/ and some plugin, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - it relies on the `[ERROR]` entry if maven produces an error:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%M in ('mvn clean install') do (
    endlocal
    echo %%M
    echo %%M | find "[ERROR]" 2>&1 > null && echo --Error durring maven execution-- && goto :endfor


)
endlocal

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%M in ('mvn next command') do (
    endlocal
    echo %%M
    echo %%M | find "[ERROR]" 2>&1 > null && echo --Error durring maven execution-- && goto :endfor


)
endlocal


goto :skipendfor

:endfor

rem put here code you want to execute if maven fails
goto :eof

:skipendfor
rem put here code you want to execute if maven succeed
goto :eof
```